# Swift import dictionary to tableviewcell

Tags: swift, tableview

I am trying to create a table view to show the content of a dictionary called `tableText<String, String>`. But in the `cellForRowAtInSection` method, when I do something like

```
let obj = tableText[indexPath.row]
```

It gives me a error saying that

```
cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, String> with an index of Int.
```

I also tried things like

```
let obj = tableText[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
```

but the error is still there.

Could you help me with this please?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have indexes, they have keys.

Comment: You declared your dictionary wrong, if you wanted to do this you would need to make the dictionary of type  tableText<Int, String>.....but if this is what you want then you should be using an array anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the values, you can get an array of values from the dictionary and used the indexPath.row on that array.

```
if let text = tableText.values[indexPath.row] as? String {
    cell.textLabel.text = text
}
```

Obviously if you need them to be sorted you would have to sort them as dictionary is not sorted based on keys.

If you wanted them sorted alphabetically, you could do this

```
let sortedText = tableText.values.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

And use this sortedText array as your datasource

Comment: So the data for table view cell must come from an array, is it correct?

Comment: @glhclhy - an array works well for a tableview or collection view as the data can be sorted etc. If you have a lot of data and use core data, you should look into NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps a lot